# Resolve the Inequality $a<b<c<d$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

We are given four discrete integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and #d# such that 
$a < b < c < d$ how can we find values for which $(ac+bd) < (bc+ad)$ holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your last inequality as
$$ b(d-c) < a(d-c), $$
and then the problem should be clear.

**Edit:**
Subtracting the RHS gives
$$ (b-a)(d-c) < 0, $$
which is not possible since $b-a>0$ and $d-c>0$ by assumption.

Comment: OP changed that 'last inequality' into your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$$bc+ad-(ac+bd)=c(b-a)-d(b-a)=-(b-a)(d-c)<0$$